# SQL query should return percentage but returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have the following lines of code:

```
ROUND((((SUM(VALOR_2)) - SQLTMP.VALOR_1) / SQLTMP.VALOR_1) * 100, 2)
```

I was hoping it would return a percentage, but it returns an ERROR instead... Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Can you give an extract of your data source ? What is the expected output ? Is SQLTMP.VALOR_1 can be zero or NULL ? Have you tried using subqueries to calculate your SUM, then calculate your division ?

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? And what does your data look like?¨

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your inputs you can try addapting this solution :

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    val1 int,
    val2 int
);

INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6)

GO
-- Your code begins here
WITH tmp_table AS (
    SELECT
        val1 AS val1,
        SUM(COLAESCE(val2, 0)) AS sum_val2
    FROM #TMP
    GROUP BY val1,val2
)
SELECT ROUND((sum_val2 - val1)/val1,2) FROM tmp_table;
-- Your code ends here
GO

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Comment: that almost got me there! No I have the foloowing line:
**(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.vendedor in (5) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN 2021-01-01 AND 2021-12-31))** That returns NULL, any idea on why?

Comment: @questionador That's a typical issue when summing a nullable column without replacing null values. You need to replace them, likely by zero. select sum(colaesce(pn.etiliquido,0))...

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    round(v1/(v2*1.0), 2) as pct 
from table
```

-- multiplying by 1.0 converts the int to decimal, round limits it to 2 places.